# How to add multiple groups value in people or group field using powershell script in server side in SP2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

How to add multiple groups value in people or group field using powershell script in server side in SP2016.
I am trying to add multiple group names in People or Group filed in list using Powershell script, could you please help on this how to do?

Answer (score 0):

You may have a try below command to set this multiple-group field:

- [Set-PnPListItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnplistitem?view=sharepoint-ps#parameters)
- [Office 365 – SharePoint – Update list items using PowerShell](https://sharepains.com/2016/06/13/office-365-sharepoint-update-list-items-using-powershell/)

[image]

> Set-PnPListItem -List "List" -Identity 1 -Values @{"mGroups" = "6","10","8"}

[image]